# Turning a Shed to Gym

Tags: shed

I have bought one of those rent to own sheds to covert into a gym.  We are looking to finish the inside with either sheet rock or wall panneling.  I am not sure of the steps.  I know I need to insulate bc I'm in Ga and to be able to handle the weather it needs insulating. My question is what is the best to use and do I need to do the vapor barior.

Answer (score 1):

Ok look, you live in the south like me and I am an insulation company owner in the south.  So a few options.  If the building is wood...do not use spray foam unless your attic space is designed for spray foam.  Essentially a spray foam building has attic spaces designed for the moisture removal.  And most buildings are not designed for this.  If your attic is air conditioned go for spray foam.  If not then you need to stick to the guidelines of your construction.  If you have metal walls then you need a vapor barrier with a 1 inch minimum gap between the metal and the vapor barrier and the wall leads up to a ventilation exhaust out the roof.  Then place your batten insulation in the wall and use what ever wall medium you wish (paneling, drywall, whatever you wish).  The air gap between the exterior wall and the vapor barrier leading to a roof vent is the key as that removes moisture and condensation as well as adds to the R Value of the insulation you install.   For a 4 inch 2x4 wall you need R13 and no more as stuffing an R19 reduces the effectiveness to R11.  So stick to the wall cavity recommended levels. R11 is a 2 inch wall, R13 is a 4 inch wall, R19 is a 6 inch wall, R30 is a 10 inch wall.  Hope this helps as Im a pro!

Comment: First time I’ve heard about the difference between wood and metal walls/framing for batt or foam insulation. I like the 1” air space idea, you’re right, it’ll vent the wall cavity and give additional R-value.

Comment: The metal verses wood information was added in case other readers are learning for their project.  If you have a wood structure attic space not designed for spray foam,  additional measures need to be taken.  For a retro fit application, a return air vent and an ac vent need to be added to the attic.  What this does is ensures a complete air return system to remove moisture that naturally travels to the attic from below.  It also removes gasses both human and from the soil that travels up.  a metal building can benefit greatly with 2# closed cell as long as there is some means of ventilation..

Answer (score 0):

The most cost effective and a good choice would be fiberglass bats.  A vapor barrier is always a good choice and very inexpensive.  What about lighting? Do you want heat? Do you need any electricity for say music/sound system? Some insulation in the floor or over the floor would be nice. P.

Comment: I have an electrician doing that part.  I didn't know the floor should be insulated thanks.